# Probability that linear combination of normal random variables exceeds a value

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I'm new to statistics, and I'm wondering how can I compute $P(2Y_1 + 4Y_2 - 3Y_3 \geq 40)$ given the following information?

- $Y$ follows a multivariate normal distribution.
- $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ follow a normal distribution.
- $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ have means $10, 12, 14$.
- $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ have variances $2, 2, 8$.
- The covariance between $Y_1, Y_2$ is $0.50$, and the covariance between $Y_1, Y_3$ is $-0.75$. The variables $Y_2$ and $Y_3$ are independent.

Here's the covariance matrix I found for $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$:

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & .50 & -.75 \\
.5 & 2 & 0 \\
-.75 & 0 & 8
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I know how to do it when $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ are all independent by using the fact that linear combinations of independent normal random variables are normal. However, I'm really not sure about how to do it in this case. I can easily find the covariance matrix, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Just knowing their means, variances and covariances along with the fact that each variables is (marginally) normal is insufficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for an analytic solution, this is what you should do. Start by defining a new variable
$$ X = 2Y_1 + 4Y_2 - 3Y_3$$
A sum of jointly normal random variables is also normal, even if the variables are not independent ([see Wikipedia article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables)). All that remains is to compute the mean and variance.

The mean of $X$ can be determined as
\begin{align*}
E[X] &= 2 E[Y_1] + 4 E[Y_2] - 3 E[Y_3] \\
&= (2 \times 10) + (4 \times 12)-(3 \times 14) \\
&= 26
\end{align*}
The variance of $X$ is slightly easier to write in matrix form. Let $Y \equiv (Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$ and $\omega \equiv (2,4,-3)$ be vectors of random variables and weights, respectively. The variance is given by

$$ Var(X) = Var(\omega'Y) = \omega'Var(Y)\omega$$

Numerically this is equal to
$$ Var(X) = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 & -3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2& .5 & -.75 \\ .5 & 2 & 0 \\ -.75 & 0 & 8 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ -3 \end{bmatrix}= 129$$
If $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal,
\begin{align*}
P(X > 40) &= 1-P\left( X \le 40 \right) \\
&= 1-P\left( \frac{X - E[X]}{\sqrt{Var(X)}} \le \frac{40 - E[X]}{\sqrt{Var(X)}} \right) \\
&= 1-P\left( Z \le \frac{40 - E[X]}{\sqrt{Var(X)}} \right) \\
&= 1-\Phi\left( \frac{40 - E[X]}{\sqrt{Var(X)}} \right) \\
&= 0.108867
\end{align*}

Comment: "A sum of normal random variables is also normal, even if the variables are not independent" - I don't think that's true. Do you have a proof?

Comment: @Paul you are correct, the necessary assumption is that the random variables are jointly gaussian (which they are in this case). The easy counterexample is $X \sim \mathcal N (0,1)$ and $Y = -X$. Then $X + Y = 0$ is not gaussian.

Comment: Another nice counterexample is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563364/prove-sum-of-unindependent-gaussian-random-variable-is-still-gaussian

Comment: Great counter examples! I have amended the statement to emphasize that "joint" normality is important. Your comments emphasize the pitfalls of focusing on the marginal distributions only.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the mean and variance of the resulting linear combination or you can also do a simulation and obtain the results.

Via simulation.

```
> covmat=matrix(c(2,0.5,-0.75,0.5,2,0,-0.75,0,8),nrow=3)
> is.positive.definite(x, tol=1e-8)
[1] TRUE
> means=c(10,12,14)
> weights=c(2,4,-3)
> mat=mvrnorm(10^7,means,covmat)
> mat=mat %*% weights
> result=sum(mat>40)/10^7
> result
[1] 0.1088587
```

Non simulated

The mean is a linear combination of means

```
> new_mean= means %*% weights
> new_mean
[1] 26
```

The variance is obtained multiplying

```
> weights %*% covmat %*% weights
     [,1]
[1,]  129
```

So your result is

```
> 1-pnorm(40,26,sqrt(129))
[1] 0.1088567
```

Comment: What language is this code in?

Comment: It is R language.